# how to detect what the user have typed in input box in html & javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my input box to detect a text like this...

```
var input = document.getElemntById("inputbox");
function buttonclick() {
  if ((input = "h")) {
    input.innerHTML = "hello";
  }
}
```

This is by button click but i need to do this `onkeyup()` but I don't know how to..
if the user type `h` the input box suddenly make it `hello`
how do I do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should have been covered in a tutorial, that you should have gone through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really just need an `onkeyup` event on your html tag.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("inputbox");

function buttonclick() {
  if (input.value === "h") {
    input.value = "hello";
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="inputbox" onkeyup="buttonclick()">
```

When the key is lifted the function `buttonclick()` is called. You also need to grab the `value` of the input as the innerHTML does not refer to what is placed within the input box but rather the actual code that would be between lets say two `<div> </div>` tags.

Comment: but if the user want to type in 'hi' how do i do it? cause when the hello come up if i backspace upto h it again come up

Comment: @RandomUser I don't understand what you are asking. Do you want it to suggest auto completes?

Answer (score 0):

Add a eventListener:

```
document.getElementById("inputbox").addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
    if (e.target.value == "h") e.target.value = "hello"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do following changes to work:

**1)** `TYPO`: You should use `getElementById` instead of `getElemntById`

```
var input = document.getElementById("inputbox");
```

**2)** You can use `keyup` event as

```
input.addEventListener( "keyup", changeInputValue )
```

**3)** When you are checking equality of two string, use `===`. `=` is for assignment.

```
input.value.trim() === "h"
```

**4)** You have to compare the `value` of the `input` with `h`.

```
input.value.trim() === "h"
```

> `NOTE:` I've used `trim` method because if user added some space
> before `h` then it will still set `hello`. You can remove it if you
> don't want.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("inputbox");

function changeInputValue() {
  if (input.value.trim() === "h") {   // input.value === "h" 
    input.value = "hello";
  }
}

input.addEventListener("keyup", changeInputValue)
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputbox" />
```